# Find the area of a contour surface plotted by ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am looking for a way to find the surface area of a contour from `ContourPlot3D`. Here is an example where I might like to find the area of the contour surface to `G` that equals -5:

```
G[x_, y_, z_] := 
  -2 Log[(2 + 2 Sqrt[((y)^2 + (z)^2)^2 + (-1 - Abs[x])^2] + 2  Abs[x])/
         (-2 + 2 Sqrt[((y)^2 + (z)^2)^2 + (1 - Abs[x])^2] + 2 Abs[x])] - 
   2 Log[(1. + 2 Sqrt[((x)^2 + (y)^2)^2 + (-0.5 - Abs[-0.5 + z])^2] + 
            2 Abs[-0.5 + z])/
         (-1. + 2 Sqrt[((x)^2 + (y)^2)^2 + (0.5 - Abs[-0.5` + z])^2] + 
            2 Abs[-0.5 + z])]

ContourPlot3D[G[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {-5}]
```

I would prefer a general method that would work even with more complicated functions than this. I don't know if there is a way to derive the area from the contour plot itself, or some other way accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem can be solved out of the box in V10 using the `ImplicitRegion` function. Lets use your function `G` and define the bounded 3D region. We can use `RegionPlot3D` to visualize the object.

```
region = ImplicitRegion[G[x, y, z] <= -5, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[region, PlotRange -> 1.5, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

Now we will use `DiscretizeRegion` to form a `MeshRegion`. The `RegionBoundary` will give the 3D surface mesh from which we can easily extract the surface area using the `Area`property.

```
dis = DiscretizeRegion[region,{{-1.5, 1.5},{-1.5,1.5},{-1.5, 1.5}},
AccuracyGoal -> 9,MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.01}];
HighlightMesh[dis, Style[1, Thin, Red]]
```

[image]

```
Area@RegionBoundary[dis]
```

> 18.7526

However a considerably slower `Method -> "ContourPlot3D"` will generate a more accurate mesh resulting in a more precise area calculation.

```
disFine = DiscretizeRegion[region,{{-1.5, 1.5},{-1.5, 1.5},{-1.5,1.5}},
Method -> "ContourPlot3D",AccuracyGoal -> 9,MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.01}]
```

[image]

```
Area@RegionBoundary[disFine]
```

> 18.7894

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `DiscretizeGraphics` with some clever options in your `ContourPlot3D`. Just add the `Option` `Lighting -> "Neutral"`:

```
gr = ContourPlot3D[G[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {-5}, Lighting -> "Neutral"] // Quiet;
```

Then you can compute the area with:

```
Area @ DiscretizeGraphics @ gr
```

> 18.8018

Here is the image from `DiscretizeGraphics`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]